# Struct with and without member

Tags: ruby, struct

I'm a new Rubyist, currently I'm going to use the Struct in class in order to create a temporary object. However, I encounter a question when I use a member in Struct like this:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :b
  B = Struct.new(:name, :print_name) do
    def print_name
      p "Hello #{name}"
    end
  end

  def initialize(input_name)
    @b = B.new(input_name)
  end
end

a = A.new('Leo')
a.b.print_name # Hello Leo
```

But I also receive the same result when my Struct B params don't include `:print_name`.

```
B = Struct.new(:name) do
...
end
```

So what is the different ? And when should I use the member param and when I'm not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first case you define a class which's initializer takes two arguments - `name` and `print_name`.

In second case you define a class which's initializer takes single argument - `name`.

These has nothing to do with the fact, that you are defining an instance method called `print_name`.

So instances of both classes (with and without `print_name` argument) have `print_name` method defined, thus both examples work identically.

The difference will be visible when you inspect created objects:

```
# first case with two arguments
foo = B.new(:a, :b)
foo.inspect
=> "#<struct B name=:a, print_name=:b>"

# second case with single argument
foo = B.new(:a)
foo.inspect
=> "#<struct B name=:a>"
```

Also, when you'll check instance methods of B class for both cases, you can see the difference:

```
# first case with two arguments
B.instance_methods false
#=> [:name, :name=, :print_name, :print_name=]

# second case with single argument
B.instance_methods false
#=> [:name, :name=, :print_name]
```

> But I also receive the same result when my Struct B params don't
>   include `:print_name`

The difference, is that in first case you are able to do the following:

```
a.b.print_name = 'new print name'
a.b.inspect
#=> "#<struct B name='Leo', print_name='new print name'>"
```

Whereas in second case it will fail:

```
a.b.print_name = 'new print name'
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'print_name=' for #<struct B name='Leo'>
```